# Serializing F# Option types

Tags: f#, json.net

Consider the F# fragment below:

```
type MyType = {  
    CrucialProperty: int
    OptionalProperty: string option 
}

let first = { CrucialProperty = 500; OptionalProperty = Some("Hello")}
let second = { CrucialProperty = 500; OptionalProperty = Some(null)}
let third = { CrucialProperty = 500; OptionalProperty = None}
```

I wish to do serialize this type using JSON.NET so I get the following strings respectively for the cases described above:

```
{"CrucialProperty":500,"OptionalProperty":"Hello"}
{"CrucialProperty":500,"OptionalProperty":null}
{"CrucialProperty":500}
```

Essentially, the problem boils down to being able to include/exclude a property in the serialized output based on the value of that property.

I've managed to find a few "OptionConverters" out there (e.g [here](https://github.com/eulerfx/JsonNet.FSharp/blob/master/src/JsonNet.FSharp/OptionConverter.fs)), but they don't quite seem to do what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend FifteenBelow's converters which work with JSON.NET but provide serialization F# types https://github.com/15below/FifteenBelow.Json (apparently moved to https://github.com/kolektiv/FifteenBelow.Json).

From their usage section:

```
let converters =
    [ OptionConverter () :> JsonConverter
      TupleConverter () :> JsonConverter
      ListConverter () :> JsonConverter
      MapConverter () :> JsonConverter
      BoxedMapConverter () :> JsonConverter
      UnionConverter () :> JsonConverter ] |> List.toArray :> IList<JsonConverter>

let settings =
    JsonSerializerSettings (
        ContractResolver = CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver (), 
        Converters = converters,
        Formatting = Formatting.Indented,
        NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)
```

Specifically what you're looking for is the the `NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore` bit.

Comment: @kornfridge - seems to be https://github.com/kolektiv/FifteenBelow.Json

Answer (score 0):

The [FSharp.JsonSkippable](https://github.com/cmeeren/FSharp.JsonSkippable) library allows you to control in a simple and strongly typed manner whether to include a given property when serializing (and determine whether a property was included when deserializing), and moreover, to control/determine exclusion separately of nullability. (Full disclosure: I'm the author of the library.)