# deserialization issue, with json.net, in F#

Tags: f#, json.net

I have a simple object to deserialize, but I do not understand the error I get.

The code is the following:

```
open System
open Newtonsoft.Json

type r =
    {
        Timestamp:           DateTime
        Currency:            string

        PreviousDeposited:   int64 option
        PreviousWithdrawn:   int64 option
        PreviousTransferIn:  int64 option
        PreviousTransferOut: int64 option
        PreviousAmount:      int64 option

        TransferIn:          int64 option
        TransferOut:         int64 option

        Amount:              int64 option

        PendingCredit:       int64 option
        PendingDebit:        int64 option
        ConfirmedDebit:      int64 option
    }


let a =
    "{
    \"account\": 117122,
    \"currency\": \"XBt\",
    \"prevDeposited\": 747841316,
    \"prevWithdrawn\": 2160000,
    \"prevTransferIn\": 1000000,
    \"prevTransferOut\": 0,
    \"prevAmount\": 656893723,
    \"prevTimestamp\": \"2020-06-13T12:00:00.005Z\",
    \"deltaDeposited\": 0,
    \"deltaWithdrawn\": 0,
    \"deltaTransferIn\": 0,
    \"deltaTransferOut\": 0,
    \"deltaAmount\": 0,
    \"deposited\": 747841316,
    \"withdrawn\": 2160000,
    \"transferIn\": 1000000,
    \"transferOut\": 0,
    \"amount\": 656893723,
    \"pendingCredit\": 0,
    \"pendingDebit\": 0,
    \"confirmedDebit\": 0,
    \"timestamp\": \"2020-06-13T12:00:00.643Z\",
    \"addr\": \"2NBMEXRW4oCiNzVUq4uVFRSsK2jtTLbtfc7\",
    \"script\": \"532102c10be2f0dc20f4285c25156aa22a0c46d2b89ccc4d1c8eaed92ea0c1a8f40c002102ceba29da1af96a0f2ef7cda6950b8be2baeb1adf12c0d5efebb70dbcaa086ba021034ab762f4ede40311e9f8bf01db0bbea578497ac6ccc8aa94a74394b05a53d94b2103d5a42b90e9d7156155661979530a09d2e12e252ef4104e5611274a7ae7e2b09454ae\",
    \"withdrawalLock\": []
    }"


JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<r> a
```

and I get this error:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Unexpected property
>   'transferOut' found when reading union. Path 'transferOut', line 18,
>   position 18.]    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.DiscriminatedUnionConverter.ReadJson(JsonReader
>   reader, Type objectType, Object existingValue, JsonSerializer
>   serializer)    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.DeserializeConvertable(JsonConverter
>   converter, JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Object existingValue)
>   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ResolvePropertyAndCreatorValues(JsonObjectContract
>   contract, JsonProperty containerProperty, JsonReader reader, Type
>   objectType)    at
>   ...

I do not understand what makes the property 'TransferOut' so special that it stops on this one, and not on any of the other identical ones before.

I have a fiddle here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/HGiia5

Comment: You might want to consider [FsPickler](https://mbraceproject.github.io/FsPickler/index.html) for this. Good for communication, but not for persistence.

Comment: @BentTranberg, it looks like an interesting library. but it can't work in this scenario since I'm getting data from a 3rd party, processing it and sending it to a queue with a several consumers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few problems here.

**Firstly**, the JSON syntax you are using for an `option` field does not match Json.NET's syntax.  If we simplify your type as follows:

```ml
type r =
    {
        TransferIn:          int64 option
        TransferOut:         int64 option
    }
```

And serialize an instance as follows:

```ml
let item : r = { TransferIn = Some 1000000L; TransferOut = None}
let json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item,Formatting.Indented)
printfn "%s" json
let item2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<r> json // No exception
```

The result is:

```
{
  "TransferIn": {
    "Case": "Some",
    "Fields": [
      1000000
    ]
  },
  "TransferOut": null
}
```

Which round-trips successfully.  Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/B3mMRp).

The simple syntax `"transferIn": 1000000` you are using for `option` fields is not implemented by [`DiscriminatedUnionConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Converters_DiscriminatedUnionConverter.htm), the converter that Json.NET uses for serializing discriminated unions including optional fields.  This mismatch is causing an exception while reading the JSON.

Relatedly, see *[Serializing F# Option types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29675087/3744182)* which has a suggestion for a nuget package that provides a [`JsonConverter`](https://github.com/kolektiv/FifteenBelow.Json/blob/master/src/FifteenBelow.Json/Converters.fs#L337) for `option<_>` that supports this simplified syntax.

**Secondly**, many of the JSON property names do not match your f# record names.  Json.NET uses an ordinal-case-insensitive algorithm to match JSON property names to f# constructor arguments and member names, but many of your JSON names do not match:

- `"prevDeposited"` does not match `PreviousDeposited`.
- `"prevWithdrawn"` does not match `PreviousWithdrawn`.
- And several others.

In fact the first property in the JSON that actually matches an `option` field is `"transferIn"`.  You are receiving an error about `"transferOut"` because it immediately follows the value of `"transferIn"` which was not deserialized successfully.

**Finally**, the error message that Json.NET is throwing for invalid JSON values for `option` fields is non-useful *when the field does not appear at the end of a JSON object*.  If I simplify the input JSON as follows:

```
{
    "transferIn": 1000000,
}
```

The we get a much more useful error message

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: No 'Case' property with union name found. Path '', line 3, position 1.

Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/AKsbSH).

But when `"transferIn"` is followed by another JSON key/value pair the error message becomes the less useful message shown in your question.  You might open an [issue](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues) with Newtonsoft asking them to improve the error message that `DiscriminatedUnionConverter` throws when the JSON value for an `option` field does not match the expected schema and there are subsequent JSON properties in the containing object.

Comment: Thanks for looking at it in depth. On point 2, it's an oversight, I converted the names I cared about and didn't check the others yet. I agree that the error is not very clear, I will open an issue and reference this thread. I get the json as is from a server. Sometimes properties are present, and sometimes they are not. Since the DU converter doesn't handle the option type, is there a better way to handle that scenario?

Comment: You would need to create a custom `JsonConverter` for `option<_>` that uses the simplified syntax.  The difficulty would be in distinguishing between `Some null` and `None` during serialization for `[AllowNullLiteral]` types.  But if you don't care about that, just from googling I found [Serializing F# Option types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30533863/3744182) (with MIT license) and [`OptionConverter`](https://github.com/haf/Newtonsoft.Json.FSharp/blob/master/src/JsonNet/Converters/OptionConverter.fs) from https://github.com/haf/Newtonsoft.Json.FSharp -- but I can't find a license for it.

Comment: I just found Microsoft.FSharpLu.Json, I will look into this as well.

Comment: It's almost there: Microsoft.FSharpLu.Json works perfectly (it's built on top of Json.net and adds its own DU parser, etc) but there is now the additional problem that it fails if there are some members in the json that are not present in the type. Setting CheckAdditionalContent <- false doesn't seem to help

Comment: Looks like `Microsoft.FSharpLu.Json` is available on dotnetfiddle, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/OLjF1S, so I'd suggest asking another question with a [mcve] showing your current code & problem.

Comment: I will do that!

Comment: here is the followup question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62364229/ignoremissingmember-setting-doesnt-seem-to-work-with-fsharplu-json-deserializer