# IgnoreMissingMember setting doesn't seem to work with FSharpLu.Json deserializer

Tags: f#, json.net, deserialization, discriminated-union

This is a following to: [deserialization issue, with json.net, in F#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62360805/deserialization-issue-with-json-net-in-f).

I am deserializing some JSON that has an extra, unbound property using [FSharpLu.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.FSharpLu.Json/).  Here is the code:

```
open System
open Newtonsoft.Json
open Microsoft.FSharpLu.Json

type r =
    {
        a: int
    }

let a =
    "{\"a\":3, \"b\":5}" 

Compact.TupleAsArraySettings.settings.MissingMemberHandling <- MissingMemberHandling.Ignore
Compact.deserialize<r> a  // doesn't work
```

Despite setting `MissingMemberHandling.Ignore` it returns a json.net error:

> Could not find member 'b' on object of type 'r'. Path 'b', line 1, position 13.

Is there a way to make this work, or is it an issue with FSharpLu.Json?

Here is the fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/OsVv1M

as a side note, there is another deserializer in FSharpLu.Json and I can get that code to work with it:

```
FSharpLu.Json.Default.Internal.DefaultSettings.settings.MissingMemberHandling <- MissingMemberHandling.Ignore
Default.deserialize<r> a
```

will work, but that deserializer doesn't handle discriminated unions... so I need to get the compact one to work.

When looking into the source of FSharpLu.Json, I found this:

```
/// Compact serialization where tuples are serialized as heterogeneous arrays
type TupleAsArraySettings =
    static member formatting = Formatting.Indented
    static member settings =
        JsonSerializerSettings(
            NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,

            // MissingMemberHandling is not technically needed for
            // compact serialization but it avoids certain ambiguities
            // that guarantee that deserialization coincides with the
            // default Json.Net deserialization.
            // (where 'coincides' means 'if the deserialization succeeds they both return the same object')
            // This allows us to easily define the BackwardCompatible
            // serializer (that handles both Compact and Default Json format) by reusing
            // the Compact deserializer.
            MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Error,
            Converters = [| CompactUnionJsonConverter(true, true) |]
        )
```

so they are explicitly setting the MissingMemberHandling to Error; maybe the solution is to instantiate the deserializer, change the setting and then use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The serializer setting you are trying to mutate, `Compact.TupleAsArraySettings.settings`, is a **static member**, as is shown in the [code](https://github.com/microsoft/fsharplu/blob/master/FSharpLu.Json/Compact.fs#L338):

> ```
> type TupleAsArraySettings =
>     static member formatting = Formatting.Indented
>     static member settings =
>         JsonSerializerSettings(
>             NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
>
>             // MissingMemberHandling is not technically needed for
>             // compact serialization but it avoids certain ambiguities
>             // that guarantee that deserialization coincides with the
>             // default Json.Net deserialization.
>             // (where 'coincides' means 'if the deserialization succeeds they both return the same object')
>             // This allows us to easily define the BackwardCompatible
>             // serializer (that handles both Compact and Default Json format) by reusing
>             // the Compact deserializer.
>             MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Error,
>             Converters = [| CompactUnionJsonConverter(true, true) |]
>         )
> ```

Since a `member` is actually a *member function (i.e. a method)* as explained *[F# for fun and profit: Attaching functions to types](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/type-extensions/)*, `settings` is actually (in c# terminology) a static property returning a new instance of `JsonSerializerSettings` each time it is invoked.  To test this, we can do:

```ml
printfn "%b" (Object.ReferenceEquals(Compact.TupleAsArraySettings.settings, Compact.TupleAsArraySettings.settings)) // prints "false"
```

Which prints "false".  Thus mutating the returned value has no effect on the behavior of `Compact`.  A static field in the c# sense would be defined by a `static let` statement; if `settings` returned such a field, mutating its contents would have had an effect.

In any event modifying the value of  `Compact.TupleAsArraySettings.settings.MissingMemberHandling` seems unwise as doing so would modify the behavior of of `Compact.deserialize` throughout your entire AppDomain in a way that might break [backwards compatibility](https://github.com/Microsoft/fsharplu/wiki/fsharplu.json#backward-compatibility-with-jsonnet) with Json.NET native serialization.  As explained in the code comments above, the setting is required to make [`BackwardCompatible.deserialize`](https://github.com/microsoft/fsharplu/blob/master/FSharpLu.Json/BackwardCompatible.fs#L50) work.  But why might that be?  Since Json.NET's native format for `option` and discriminated unions looks like:

```
{
  "a": {
    "Case": "Some",
    "Fields": [
      3
    ]
  }
}
```

We can guess that `MissingMemberHandling` is used to trap situations where `"Case"` and `"Fields"` are found or not, and switch from one algorithm to the other.

**If you are certain you do not need to deserialize f# types in Json.NET format**, it seems you should be able to use [`CompactUnionJsonConverter`](https://github.com/microsoft/fsharplu/blob/master/FSharpLu.Json/Compact.fs#L77) directly as follows:

```ml
let settings = JsonSerializerSettings(
    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
    Converters = [| CompactUnionJsonConverter(true, true) |]
)
let c = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<r>(a, settings)
let json2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(c, Formatting.Indented, settings)
```

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FFpG52).

Comment: as it turns out.. with more complex types it will not work. Maybe FSharpLu's converter is not handling it properly. I posted a follow up question with a fiddle at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62377246/another-failure-at-deserializing-data-with-discriminated-unions-in-f